# How can i install php 64 bits.

Tags: php, binary, xampp, unpack

I'm developing inside xampp and everything runs fine but i have a new funtionality which requires me to read from a binary file and then unpack some bytes to turn them in human readable info.

One of the byte chunks that i need to read requires me to use

`unpack("P*", $data)`but when im trying to do this it keeps telling me :

unpack(): 64-bit format codes are not available for 32-bit versions of PHP

And i understand what is going on, the "P*" its supposed to be a 64-bit unsigned long long number so php returns an error.

But i been digging a lot to implement or change the php inside xampp but i cant really find a concrete answer.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a windows x64 build of xampp. On what features of xampp do you depend? (Is it just: "bring httpd+php+mysql to my computer"?)

Comment: I require php 64 bit version in order to use some of this tags inside the unpack() function.

'q' signed long long (always 64 bit, machine byte order)
'Q' unsigned long long (always 64 bit, machine byte order)
'J' unsigned long long (always 64 bit, big endian byte order)
'P' unsigned long long (always 64 bit, little endian byte order)

Comment: Yes, I understand. Do you _have_ (for some reason) to use XAMPP for this? Or would another installation, e.g. via apache lounge+windows.php.net+mysql.com, do?

Comment: No i'm not bound to use Xampp i will try to research what ur suggesting.
Thanks

Comment: It's not quite as easy as clicking on next,next,next but it's definitley on the doable side of things ;-) Just make sure you have the necessary visual studio redistributables installed. If you pick the php7 x64 build from windows.php.net that would be VC14 and apache lounge also has VC14 builds. The redist package is available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984